# Is server-side validation necessary for donations using PayPal checkout REST?

Tags: php, rest, paypal, server-side

I have been following this page in the documentation to create a PayPal checkout integration for the purpose of allowing visitors to a site to make donations: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integrate/#6-verify-the-transaction. It seems that the more simple donations buttons cannot be used, as it is a requirement that donations are saved to a database table.

I have so far implemented all of the integration up to some of part 6, which verifies the transaction on the server. The code provided on the page (I am using PHP) is not clear and all of the examples of server side validation that I can find refer to purchases, which do not apply to donations. However, even without this, in sandbox mode the integration appears to work. Would this also work in live mode without server validation (and there is no concern of a third-party editing "prices", as this is a donation, so why not let them pay whatever they like?)? If server validation is necessary, what resources are there that exaplain/demonstrate how to do server-side validation of transactions for simple payments (e.g. donations) that do not involve purchases?

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your own requirements, you want it to call your server after capture, so that it saves a record of the transaction in your server. Everything else is optional, and as you mention may not be needed for any purpose.